# Characters of a finite group

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, representation-theory, characters

Recently, I have been studying about Character Theory of Finite Groups, mostly from "Groups and Representations" by J. Alperin & R. Bell.
In the aforementioned textbook, the characters of a finite group $G$ is studied using the the group algebra of $G$ over the field of complex numbers. However, I know the characters of a finite group $G$ could be studied over any field $F$.

So, these are my questions, for which not only do I appreciate your answers, but, more importantly, I would be grateful if you could mention good references for supplementary studies, of course referring to the adequate parts which answer my following questions:

1. Let assume we want to study characters of a finite group $G$ over a field $F$. Would it be possible to obtain all the information we need to know about the irreducible characters of $G$ over $F$ by studying the characters of $G$ over appropriate subfields (or overfields) of $F$. If so, how could one make the vague idea of "appropriate subfield (or overfield)" a bit more precise?
2. We define the virtual characters (sometimes referred to as generalized characters) of a group $G$ as all the $\mathbb Z$-linear combinations of the irreducible characters of $G$, which forms a ring. What special information do we obtain by this generalization?

Thanks for your help in advance. In particular, good references, with precise address for reading more about these questions would be highly appreciated.

Comment: It would take too long to answer this question properly, so I will just make a couple of remarks. Firtly, it is important whether or not ${\rm char}(F)$ divides $|G|$. If not, or if ${\rm char}(F)=0$, then you are within the realm of ordinary character theory, which is broadly speaking independent of the characteristic. If so, then things are more complicated - this is modular character theory. As for subfields/overfields, it matters whether $F$ contains $n$-th roots of 1 for various $n$ dividing $|G|$. If $F$ contains *enough* roots of 1 then the theory is much the same as for ${\mathbb C}$.

Comment: Dear Derek,
Thanks for your comment. I clearly see how the point you mentioned about the characteristic of the field could be crucial (Maschke's Theorem). But, even in that case, it seems studying characters of a group $G$ over a field like $\mathbb R$ could be different from an algebraically closed overfield of that, such as $\mathbb C$. Moreover, in the other case, I cannot completely understand what "enough" means here when in your last sentence  you mentioned :"If F contains enough roots of 1 then the theory is much the same as for C"

Comment: Well ${\mathbb R}$ does not contain fourth roots of 1, and hence the difference. So some reptns are irreducible over ${\mathbb R}$ but split into two reptns of the same degree (with conjugate characters) over ${\mathbb C}$. There is an extra complication in that an irreducible character may take only real values, but the corresponding reptn cannot be written over ${\mathbb R}$. An example istThe 2-dimensional character of $Q_8$. The meaning of *enough* depends on the group, but if $F$ contains all $|G|$-th roots of $1$ then you can be sure that all irreducible reptns can be written over $F$.

Comment: Dear Derek,
Thanks for you second comment. I had the same idea when I asked about the difference between characters of $G$ over $\mathbb R$ and $\mathbb C$, which you explicitly mentioned.
I was wondering if you could introduce a good reference from which I could read a bit more about the argument you made above, regarding the cases when the conditions of Maschke's theorem are not satisfied.

Comment: So you are looking for references for books in Modular Representation Theory, which is a difficult subject. I don't think I can do any better than refer you to the discussion here: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/55983

Comment: Thanks Derek for your comments and the link.